# What to do when searching on more than one word with django filter

Tags: python, regex, django, django-filters

I made a filter where you can search on different keywords and it works.

My problem is that when i am trying to search on more than one keyword.

How do I make it possible to filter the search so it can separate each word?

Here is a picture how it looks:

First picture shows when i only search on one key word, and second shows when i search on two: [image] 
[image]

Here is my code for The model class:

```
class Task(managers.Model):
keywords = models.ManyToManyField('Keyword', blank=True, related_name='event_set')
objects = managers.DefaultSelectOrPrefetchManager.from_queryset(managers.TaskQuerySet)()
```

And here is my Filter class:

```
class TaskFilterSet(BaseFilterSet):

keywords = django_filters.MethodFilter(action="filter_keywords")

class Meta:
    model = models.Task

def filter_keywords(self, queryset, value):
    from django.db.models import Q
    return queryset.filter(Q(keywords__word__icontains=value))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets suppose you are searching for the following Keywords: `foo` and `boo`. And you have the following relation:

```
search['foo','boo']
object.keywords['foo','boo','woo']
```

You can iterate over `object.keywords` and see if one of the search objects you have matches one of the `keywords` in `object`. If it does, you return the `filter` containing that object.